# How to make a topographic map with a Digital Terrain Model shapefile?

Tags: qgis, topography

I'm 2 weeks in self-learning QGIS so I don't know if my question is the same with the suggested similar ones.

I'm making a map like this. A map of a mountain with a "mountain-like" texture.
[image]

[By u/coolrivers from r/qgis](https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/ay6b8j/amazed_how_much_qgis_i_learned_in_one_day_that/)

**I have a Digital Terrain Model [shapefile](http://philgis.org/province-page/camarines-sur) of our region and how do I have a texture like that?**

I tried the Batch Hillshader and its results into error everytime I run it.

This is what the shapefile looks like.
[image]

Edit. It's a digital terrain model, not a digital elevation model

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the attribute table from your file? It doesn't look like a 'digital terrain model', but more like a Land Cover Map.

Comment: Having now downloaded and checked the data, what you have is a Land Cover Map. This dataset is not suitable for creating the map that you are after, as it does not contain information about elevation.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen Looks like it's a land cover map. Not a DTM.

"as it does not contain information about elevation."

Thanks for this. I now have a clue how to find proper elevation data.